# Neo4j load csv creating more relationships than lines in CSV

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a file, `people.csv`, with values `(NPI, FirstName, LastName)`. This Cypher query populates the data base with as many People nodes as there are lines of the csv.

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///people.csv' AS row
CREATE (:Person {id: toInteger(row.NPI), first_name: row.FirstName, last_name: row.LastName});

CREATE INDEX FOR (p:Person) ON (p.id);
```

There is another file, `refers.csv`, with values `(ReferNPI, ReferredNPI, NumReferrals)`. This query produces many thousand times more relationships than there are lines of the file, even though each line is intended to represent one relationship.

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///refers.csv' AS row
MATCH (refer:Person {id: toInteger(row.ReferNPI)})
MATCH (referred:Person {id: toInteger(row.ReferredNPI)})
CREATE (refer)-[:REFERS {num_refers: toInteger(row.NumReferrals)}]->(referred)
```

It would appear that my understanding of Cypher's semantics is incorrect; perhaps it's doing every possible combination of nodes that match these two patterns. How can I ensure that each only one pair of nodes is connected per line of the csv?

Comment: Is it possible to share the files: people.csv and refers.csv?  The index of Person is id and might be different to ReferNPI or ReferredNPI. So you might be creating duplicate person nodes in people.csv. If it happens, one relationship in refers.csv will create >1 relationship in refers.csv.

Comment: I cannot share them, as the people they refer to might be real. Though it would appear that in people.csv, the NPI (stored in the nodes as the id attribute) is not unique. I suppose that is the explanation?

Comment: No problem. I will post an answer to get +pts. :D

Comment: Let me know if there are any other questions I can answer for you about the schema of the data in general.

Comment: no more questions. You are also correct to say that "it's doing every possible combination of nodes". It is indeed doing a cartesian product when doing lines 1-2 in MATCH statements. So if two refer have same NPI and one referred NPI, it will do 2 x 1 = 2 relationships instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your people.csv files, the NPI is not the defined index and rather the id generated by neo4j. Thus, if NPI is duplicated value in people.csv, you will create duplicated relationships in refers.csv.

for example:

```
People.csv contains 

 p1: NPI:123 (id generated is 789
 p2: NPI:123 (id is 790)

Refers.csv
    referNPI: 123  referred: 345
```

Instead of having one relationship (id:789)-[: REFERS]->(NPI: 345), you will created another relationship from (id:790) ->(NPI: 345) because both person1 and person2 have the same NPI.

===Edited to answer the comment below.

To show that Person has duplicate nodes, try running this cypher query:

```
 MATCH (p:Person) 
 WITH p.id as pNPI, collect(p) as person
 RETURN pNPI, size(person) as counts LIMIT 5
```

I would suggest that you do the following:

1. Change CREATE to MERGE so that it will not create duplicates
2. Use ID instead of id, neo4j is case sensitive
3. Create a CONSTRAINT on ID, this will prevent you on creating duplicate Person with the same ID(NPI).
   CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Person) assert n.ID IS UNIQUE;

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How could the NPI, which is a value in the csv file, be something created by neo4j?

Comment: I mean you created multiple Person nodes with the same id value (NPI). id is a reserved attribute in neo4j which is an object id generated when the node was created. Try  creating an index on id and you will see that Person has >1 id value (NPI)

Comment: In my instance, each node has an `id` attribute and an `<id>` attribute, the latter being one that I did not set.

Comment: You created an index which is not unique, so the load person script allows duplicates. If you can ensure the csv file have unuque NPI values, use CREATE else use MERGE and create unique index on id beforehand.